Expansion of a function $(1-x)^{-n}$
Write the expansion of the series: $(1-x)^{-n}$.
I haven’t got the solution

Consider writing the binomial coefficients as a polynomial and plugging in $-n$:
\begin{gather*}
\binom nk = \frac{n(n - 1)(n - 2) \cdots (n - k)}{k!}
\end{gather*}
Note that this only works for $k \in \mathbb Z$

Depending on what we can assume to be known, you can either use the Taylor series of the function $f(x)=(1-x)^{-n}$ at $x=0$ (get the first few derivatives and see if you can find a pattern) or you can use the Binomial series directly.

We begin by recalling that
$
\displaystyle \frac {1}{1 - x} = \sum_{k \ge 0} {x}^{k}.
$
Differentiate both sides:
$
\displaystyle \frac {1}{{\left( 1 - x \right)}^{2}} = \sum_{k \ge 1} k {x}^{k - 1}.
$
Do the same thing again:
$
\displaystyle \frac {2}{{\left( 1 - x \right)}^{3}} = \sum_{k \ge 2} k \left( k - 1 \right) {x}^{k - 2}.
$
Again:
$
\displaystyle \frac {6}{{\left( 1 - x \right)}^{4}} = \sum_{k \ge 3} k \left( k - 1 \right) \left( k - 2 \right) {x}^{k - 3}.
$
Again:
$
\displaystyle \frac {24}{{\left( 1 - x \right)}^{5}} = \sum_{k \ge 4} k \left( k - 1 \right) \left( k - 2 \right) \left( k - 3 \right) {x}^{k - 4}.
$
Now we see the pattern. It can be proved by induction that
$
\displaystyle \frac {n!}{{\left( 1 - x \right)}^{n + 1}} = \sum_{k \ge n} \frac {k!}{\left( k - n \right)!} {x}^{k - n}.
$
Let $k \mapsto k + n$, so
$
\displaystyle \frac {n!}{{\left( 1 - x \right)}^{n + 1}} = \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac {\left( k + n \right)!}{k!} {x}^{k}.
$
Rearrangement yields
$
\displaystyle \boxed {\frac {1}{{\left( 1 - x \right)}^{n + 1}} = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom {k + n}{n} {x}^{k}.}
$
